# parsing JSON using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I've got a page that will get a quick login check and access a web service for some JSON data.  The data it's returning looks like this:

```
{ 'RESPONSE' : 'INVALID','CAMPAIGNID' : '0','MORELINK' : '' }
```

The code I'm using to get this data and attempt to pop a modal window based on the information is:

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Login.asmx/Logon",
            data: strData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                $('#divResp').html(response.d);
                $(response.d).each(function(index,item){
                    alert(item.campaignid);
                });
                if (res.indexOf('invalid') >= 0){                       
                    //invalid account information UNP                       
                    foo = "You entered an invalid account number or password";
                    showDialog('screenActivate.asp',test_imgName);
                } 
                if (res.indexOf('none') >=0) {
                    //do not deliver splash screen
                    foo = "No splash screen for YOU!";
                } 
                if (res.indexOf('error') >=0) {
                    //general error
                    foo = "You entered an error";
                }
                if (res.indexOf('frozen') >=0) {
                    //member is locked out from numberous failed attempts
                    foo = "You have too many failed attempts.  Your account has been locked";
                }
                if (res.indexOf('.png') >=0) {
                    imgName = (response.d);
                    showDialog('screenActivate.asp',test_imgName);
                }
                alert(foo);
                $('#divResp').html(response.d);
            }
        });
        $('#divQuery').ajaxError(function(evt, request, settings){
            $('#divResp').html("Web services timeout.  Please try again.");             
        });
    }
```

The challenge is, either I get no information (Undefined) or as is with this current iteration, an error from Firebug that states *uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 'INVALID'*

Am I not parsing the JSON response properly?

**Relevant comment to answer**

I pasted: `"d":"{ 'RESPONSE' : 'INVALID','CAMPAIGNID' : '0','MORELINK' : '' } "` into the jsonlint.com and that tool says the JSON is valid. When I attempt to loop through `response.d` with an each statement, it seems to go character by character.

Comment: Always validate the repsonse first e.g. with http://www.jsonlint.com. In your case you are definitely not getting a valid JSON.

Answer (score 6):

JSON spec requires the use of double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`)

Official JSON string parsing Diagram (from http://www.json.org)

http://www.json.org/string.gif

**in response to your comment...**

ok, here's the deal...

```
"d":"{ 'RESPONSE' : 'INVALID','CAMPAIGNID' : '0','MORELINK' : '' } "
```

IS valid JSON... but it is simply an object with a `d` property that contains the string...

```
"{ 'RESPONSE' : 'INVALID','CAMPAIGNID' : '0','MORELINK' : '' } "
```

data that would work the way you expect would look like this...

```
{"d": {"RESPONSE":"INVALID","CAMPAIGNID":"0","MORELINK":""}}
```

Comment: I pasted: "d":"{ 'RESPONSE' : 'INVALID','CAMPAIGNID' : '0','MORELINK' : '' } " into the jsonlint.com and that tool says the JSON is valid.  When I attempt to loop through response.d with an each statement, it seems to go character by character.

Comment: alright, I have the JSON properly coded, but I'm still not iterating through the object and getting name/value pairs.  If I alert the return it just gives me Object [object]  How do I determine the JSON contents?  I'd like to know the campaignid, and if there is a morelink.

Comment: An object is not meant to be iterated over... just do something like this...  `if (response.d.MORELINK.length > 0) { alert(response.d.CAMPAIGNID); }`

Comment: I'm getting a response.d.MORELINK is undefined error in Firebug.   I'd offer to paste code, but it's exactly as you typed above.  This is why I turned to Stack for help, because #$^* just isn't working as it should.

Comment: Sorry! forgot the wrapping curly braces... fixed it in the answer.

Comment: OK, this is the JSON that is coming back from the POST:

"{ "RESPONSE" : "ERROR","CAMPAIGNID" : "0","MORELINK" : "" } "  and I can't seem to access the individual elements of the object.

Comment: how do you see this string? have you done this??? `console.log(response)` in the success function?  this will output the response object to your chrome/firebug javascript console.

Comment: It's giving me a null when I try using the $.parseJSON(response) to get the string results from the object.  I've tried using response.toString in the parseJSON function, and of course the staight JSON.parse like you mentioned.  No luck.

Comment: ....  ok, `$.ajax` automatically parses the json for you when you set the `dataType` option to json, so in the first line of your `success` function, put `console.log(response)`...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@jondavidjohn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218859/parsing-json-using-jquery-not-so-rewarding/8218875#8218875) (+1), you're also referencing the variable `res`, which is not defined.

Comment: I removed the declaration for res in troubleshooting the JSON data issue.  It was right were the alert() was. :)